# Rewrite Query String in Opencart 2.x

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

i want to rewrite URL in opencart 2.x like below

**Original URL:**

```
http://example.com/order?order_id=DF45ER
```

**URL shall look like**

```
http://example.com/order/DF45ER
           or
http://example.com/order/order_id/DF45ER
```

I tried it using

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^order_id/([^/]*)\.html$ /order?order_id=$1 [L]
```

Then in Controller, i tried replacing

```
'href' => $this->url->link('ord/infomrt', 'order_id/' . $enc_odid, 'SSL'),
```

With this

```
'href' => $this->url->link('order_id/' . $enc_odid . '.html', 'SSL'),
```

But this did not work. **Do i need to modify or create new $this->url->link() function?**

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^order_id/([^/]*)$ /order?order_id=$1 [L]
```